# How can I print print the date with arabic characters in python

Tags: python, datetime, arabic

Hi I'm creating a PDF document in Python with FPDF. I can generate a PDF with  static text with arabic letters. But how can i use eg. strftime to create the date, dont know if they use a diffent date format, but how to print a arabic date?

Comment: A Hijrah date? As far as I have understood that calendar system comes in many variants, so it may be more complex than it sounds as first. Or just a Gregorian calendar date using Arabic letters and digits?

Comment: Hi Ole. I think just a Gregorian calender format with Arabic letters and digits would be fine